# SQL server connection pooling in java exceeds 600, cause database to crash?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, connection-pooling

I have a application which requires Connection pooling, as the server has several clients communicating to it at same time, which may be around 10k. And when i limit maxActive =200, updation of the database slows.

Application programming i have did in Java. 
Connection pooling i am doing with the help of Tomcat Context.xml.
Database i am using SQL server 2005.

Please help me in doing the correct way of pooling, such that my application does not slows down.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of correct way of pooling, you have to find out by inspecting with how many active connections you are able to get maximum throughput.

```
1) Check any inactive connections which are not closed.
2) Do some analysis to find out the root causes or when it's eating up lot of connections.
```

Ideally for any project the most common parameters I have seen is 200 - 300 active connections, if it exceeds more than that it's more likely an enterprise application for which you have to rely on infrastructure rather than programmatically.

After a certain threshold you should look at clustering of databases as you can tweak it to a certain extent once you have identified there are no places in program to optimize.

Comment: according to the code, i am taking connection from pool and after every execution of the statement i am closing connection with  _conn.close();_ and also in the **finally** block

Comment: What could be the reason of so many sleeping connections. I could not able to figure it out.

Comment: It is only possible to find out if I have look at code base. If possible to share your screen, then I can help you out. email me the information to connect to phani(dot)rocks at hotmail.com